# Error code 2503 - Cannot install software on Windows 7 (64Bit)

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bios, file-permissions

A short while ago, I had my hard drive die on me and at the same time my 1Tb backup drive!
I took it back to the guy I bought the PC from and although the backup drive could not be recovered, he managed to get my machine working again by making a minor change in the BIOS which then got it out of that continuous loop it found itself in after multiple BSOD episodes.

Everything seems to be working fine but yesterday when I tried to save something from Google Chrome, I got and insufficient permission problem and when I try to install software, I get an error of 2503.

I have already followed the suggestions [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-code-2503-when-installing-programs/972e9fab-4251-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=7899426d-4f22-415a-bd93-191b67bc4aa0) but none of this worked for me.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT: This started happening after I tried running a number of tests to get the machine working, including a previous restore point.**

Comment: I'm also checking these posts. http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/138183-Installation-Error-codes-2502-amp-2503

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you try to save to a different location on your hard drive. Try saving it to the downloads folder, or desktop or My Documents and see if the error perists.

Comment: Hi Dave. This happens if I try to install or uninstall anything/anywhere on the PC.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean to say install? The post says save from Google although it could be related to my theory and potential fix

Comment: Hi Dave. The two it seems are related. I cannot save from Google Chrome to any folder, nor can I install or uninstall software. It's a permission issue, but how and why this would happen I am not sure. I have added an edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error happen on my windows 10 machine. The MSI software would not install.  It had something todo with the permissions.  I opened a console window as an administrator and when to my downloads folder where the msi installer was and just ran that in the console.  It installed without the 2503 2502 error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that although you are an administrator (I assume you are), you don't have ownership of the "computer".

Please open Explorer and right click on the C drive and select properties.

In the new Window, select security tab, click advanced.

Now, in here, go the Owner tab. I would assume the owner is not your account. You can click edit and make any user the owner, or it may be better to make the 'TrustedInstaller' the owner. You will need to do this for all subfolders etc and this could take a long time.

I suggest you read up about taking ownership first (actually, if you follow my advice, before changing the ownership there is a link to learn more about it) and then go for it.

Answer (score -1):

Things you can try is

1. Run a system file check `sfc /scannow`
2. Check whether there is enough permission for the installer drive/folder
3. Check `Windows Installer` service is running
4. Re register the Windows installer